# Bash-like, non-rotating filename tab completion with PowerShell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, tab-completion

Under Windows, using PowerShell, is it possible to make the filename suggestion (using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key) work like with bash under Linux?

Let's assume a directory contains 3 directories: `example1`, `example` and `examination`.

On Windows (by default), if you type `cd ex` and <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will auto-suggest `cd .\examination`. Subsequent uses of <kbd>Tab</kbd> will rotate the suggestion between `example1`, `example` and `examination`.

Using bash (typically under Linux), if you type `cd ex` and <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will auto-complete until the character where the filenames start to differ: `cd exam`. Another use of <kbd>Tab</kbd> then suggests which directories are available:

```
$ cd exam
examination/ example1/    example2/
```

Then, if you type <kbd>p</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will auto-complete to `example`, and so on (here, offering a choice between `example1` and `example2`).

Is there a way to make the filename suggestion work in a tree-like search like this, instead of rotating through the names?

(I'm mainly interested in file names. Bash can also refine this selection based on the file type, for example only directories for `cd`, which would be good, but having the file name selection itself would be enough.)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264655/how-to-make-powershell-tab-completion-work-like-bash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default completion behavior is the result of using the command window, which handles keyboard input.

As of PowerShell v3, the ISE is worth considering as a full-time shell, and has modern completion behavior (and colorization!).

If you really want BASH-style completion in a PowerShell command Window, get **PSReadline**:

https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine

There is an older, less featured, and unmaintained project also called PSReadline here:
<strike>http://nivot.org/nivot2/post/2012/09/12/Emulating-Bash-GNU-Readline-with-PowerShell-30.aspx</strike>
http://nivot.org/blog/post/2012/09/12/Emulating-Bash-GNU-Readline-with-PowerShell-30