# Windows command abbreviation and command completion

Tags: windows, command-line

In some OS (i.e. IOS, JUNOS,  FortiOS), it supports abbreviation like `sh ver` is equal to `show version`. For the shortcut key, if you type `sh` and press TAB, it will complete the command as `show`. Is it possible to have such configuration in Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

The legacy command prompt offers [`doskey`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSKEY) for operations like [defining aliases](http://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html) (macros).

The recommended shell for Windows is now PowerShell, which also offers the `alias` command and includes a set of built-in aliases and smarter auto-completion for cmdlets. The completion mode still defaults to the standard Windows mode, but it's possible to [get it to emulate bash-like completion](https://superuser.com/questions/502762/bash-like-non-rotating-filename-tab-completion-with-powershell).